# Overriding keyboard shortcuts on a RichEditBox?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

Is there a way to disable, or better yet override, keyboard shortcuts on the WinRT RichEditBox control? I want to be able to disable the bold and italic formatting when you press Ctrl-B and Ctrl-I.

I'm avoiding using a regular plain TextBox because I want to use the formatting options in the RichEditBox to add syntax highlighting to the text. If the user can manipulate the styling within the box, that won't work.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try the solution from the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/260716/override-shortcut-keys-on-net-richtextbox

Comment: @jsirr13 That applies to WinForms. The RichEditBox in WinRT doesn't have the ModifierKeys property, nor does the Control base class.

Comment: You might try handling the [`KeyDown`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.keydown) event of your [`RichExitBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows.ui.xaml.controls.richeditbox) and discarding the appropriate control keys.

Comment: @dbc I've tried setting `Handled` on `KeyRoutedEventArgs`for both `KeyDown` and `KeyUp` to true. This prevents me from typing anything at all into the box... but I'm still able to bold and italicize any text that was already there.

Comment: Maybe something along the lines of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21203494/richeditbox-using-ctrli-to-set-italic-text-deletes-the-text.  You can try to check if the control key is currently held down with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13001215/detect-if-modifier-key-is-pressed-in-keyroutedeventargs-event

Comment: @dbc I've played around with those and there may be some promise there as far as detecting when to override the key command. The problem that I'm facing is that even if I got that to work, I don't know how to actually override the key command. That's what setting `Handled` to `true` should have done, and it works for everything *except* bolding and italicizing text.

Answer (score 2):

At long last I found the answer in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9480839/how-do-i-call-the-base-class-implementation-textboxonkeydown-in-my-override): the `OnKeyDown` method of a text control gets called before the `KeyDown` event is fired, so rather than listening to the `KeyDown` event, you must create a subclass of `RichEditBox` and override the `OnKeyDown` method. Then in your XAML markup or wherever you're instantiating the `RichEditBox`, use your custom subclass instead. As a somewhat-related example, I created an override of `TextBox` that prevents undo and redo operations:

```
[Windows::Foundation::Metadata::WebHostHidden]
public ref class BetterTextBox sealed : public Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::TextBox
{
public:
    BetterTextBox() {}
    virtual ~BetterTextBox() {}
    virtual void OnKeyDown(Windows::UI::Xaml::Input::KeyRoutedEventArgs^ e) override
    {
        Windows::System::VirtualKey key = e->Key;
        Windows::UI::Core::CoreVirtualKeyStates ctrlState = Windows::UI::Core::CoreWindow::GetForCurrentThread()->GetKeyState(Windows::System::VirtualKey::Control);
        if ((key == Windows::System::VirtualKey::Z || key == Windows::System::VirtualKey::Y) &&
            ctrlState != Windows::UI::Core::CoreVirtualKeyStates::None)
        {
            e->Handled = true;
        }

        // only call the base implementation if we haven't already handled the input
        if (!e->Handled)
        {
            Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::TextBox::OnKeyDown(e);
        }
    }
};
```